# How to reference System.Data in c#

Tags: c#, .net, system

I'm looking to reference the System.Data namespace for interacting with MS Access however, whenever I attempt to use `using System.Data` The namespace is not found.

Is there some other reference that I need to add to my project.

Working with .net 4.6.2. Due to the nature of my project (acad objectARX 2018 based) I need to use this version of .net (or at least I think I do, can you use different framework versions for different class libraries?)

Thanks,
SOliver.

Edit: Turns out I was creating a class library(.net standard) where I was looking for class library (.net framework)

Cheers for the help.

Comment: Did you add a reference to the DLL, or did you just add the `using` statement?

Comment: No, I'm not even sure which dll I would be looking for or where it will be.

Comment: Right click on your project, add reference, make sure System.Data is checked.

Comment: Add the System.Data assembly reference

Comment: When you go under your project tree and expand References, is System.Data in there?

Comment: Sybren: I can't find the reference in the add reference feature. I can see other options such as `System.Drawing` in the COM reference list but not Data.

Hoodaticus: No, the reference is not available there.

Answer (score 4):

1. Right click on your project
2. In the Add Reference dialog box, click
       the Assemblies, make sure System.Data is checked.

Comment: Thanks for the response. There's no .net option in the reference manager only, Assemblies, Projects, Shared Projects, COM and Browse. None of which contain System.Data.

Comment: Should be under Assemblies

Comment: My bad, should be in Assemblies.  Are you on .NET 4 or higher?

Comment: Can't see it in assemblies (even using the search feature). Yeah, I'm using .net 4.6.2

Comment: It's been awhile, but do you have Entity Framework installed?

Comment: Figured it out. Had created a .net standard class library where I should've used .net framework class library. C# is proving trickier than I thought it would be... Thanks for the help